# How can i extract some strings using grep and regular expression

Tags: regex, grep

I have some lines likes:

```
2017-03-10 21:55:57.426 INFO  es.sd.phase.kpi.KPIEventNotifier -       ID-es2rxsf01v-54870-1489080967572-0-2605574 - KPI1: 52 ms [ValidationPhase:1#TransformationPhase:8#EnrichmentPhase:10#DynamicRouterPhase:4#PoseseadorPhase:29#generateACK:0#EndPhase:0]
```

The output of grep command have to show:

```
2017-03-10 21:55:57.426 KPI1: 52 ms
```

I tried agroup both with:

```
tail -F file.log | grep -Po "(.\*INFO).*(KPI1.*ms)"
```

But obviosly only show:

```
2017-03-10 21:55:57.426 INFO  es.sd.phase.kpi.KPIEventNotifier -       ID-es2rxsf01v-54870-1489080967572-0-2605574 - KPI1: 52 ms
```

We need avoid this part:

```
INFO  es.sd.phase.kpi.KPIEventNotifier -       ID-es2rxsf01v-54870-1489080967572-0-2605574 -
```

And only show this part:

```
2017-03-10 21:55:57.426 KPI1: 52 ms
```

Thanks
Javi

Comment: Is that whole thing just one line that is always formated the exact same way?

Comment: Using awk is perhaps a better option.

Comment: If it is, you could use cut -f 1,2,9-11 -d " "

Comment: Yes, @klutt, Is always formated by the same way.

Comment: Or `sed 's/INFO.*\(KPI1.*ms\).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` can not omit/treat *non-capturing* groups(*as they shouldn't be captured*) of variable length like `(?:INFO.*)` or `(?=INFO.*)` from the final output. Actually, we can't mark suquences of variable length as *non-captured*.
Use `sed` command instead(to get only needed matched groups):

```
sed -En 's/^([-0-9.: ]+)INFO.*?(KPI.+ms).*/\1\2/p' file.log
```

`-E` option, allows extended regular expressions

`/p` flag, tells to print only matched substrings

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using grep and another tools whatever it is to filter the grep result, you can use awk that is field based. Using the default field separator (whitespace), you can write:

```
awk '$3=="INFO" && $8=="KPI1:"{print $1,$2,$8,$9,$10}' file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easily solved with the cut command:

```
tail -F file.log | cut -f 1,2,9-11 -d " "
```

I often use cut instead of awk, since I think the syntax looks cleaner.